# If-Then Block Issue in SAS

Tags: date, if-statement, sas

I am working on writing a SAS code and since I am new to SAS (Have worked on R all the time), I am having trouble understanding the date formats in SAS.

I Have a SAS data set **Sales_yyyymm** and I am creating a code that takes the user's input of a date value, and if Sales data exists for that date, I need to create a flag as 1 else as 0. Currently I am using this code -

```
%Let check_date = 20010120;

 Data A;
  Set B;
 If date=&check_date then Date_Flag = 1;
 else Date_Flag = 0;
 run;
```

`date`  is the Date column in my SAS data set `Sales_yyyymm` and the values are like `20130129`, `20110412`, `20140120` etc.

But if I run this code, I get all my `Date_Flag` values as 0. The IF condition is being ignored and I am not sure how or why this is happening.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the `date` column is infact a date which is formatted to show as yyyymmdd i.e., date is not a 8digit integer. Check `proc contents data =<your dataset>; run;` output and report back the type & format of `date` column

Comment: And another thing - in SAS date literals are supposed to be "DDMMMYYYY"d format. This will matter if in fact `date` column is really stored as a date type column.

Comment: I just checked and found that `date` column is of type NUM and Len 4 and format YYMMDDN8.

Comment: `Format` in SAS is solely a way to print something that looks nice to human eyes - akin to in c++ using `sprintf`.  It has no bearing on the underlying value nor is it permitted to be used in equalities (without some other function, like `put`, which is the direct equivalent of `sprintf`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read [Understanding How SAS Handles Dates](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001397898.htm) article to get how SAS internally stores a date and how arithmetic on date including comparisions are carried out.

> In SAS, every date is a unique number on a number line. Dates before
> January 1, 1960, are negative numbers; those after January 1, 1960,
> are positive. Because SAS date values are numeric variables, you can
> sort them easily, determine time intervals, and use dates as
> constants, as arguments in SAS functions, or in calculations.

As I mentioned in the comments you really need to specify your date literals in "ddmmmyyyy"d format.

So, `%Let check_date = 20010120;` should be written as:

```
%Let check_date = 20JAN2001;

 Data A;
  Set B;
 If date="&check_date."d then Date_Flag = 1;
 else Date_Flag = 0;
 run;
```

`20010120` translated into SAS date goes beyond the valid range SAS can handle. Ex: `2001012` - note there is no zero at the end, corresponds to `"03AUG7438"` - yes, that's year 7438!!

Whereas `14995` is the integer that SAS understands to be the date `20JAN2001`